# how make a multiplication in assembly x8086 but without mul command

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I need to make a program how pick two number between 0 and 9 and multiply they but I can only use SHL, SHR or ROR,ROL commands

```
;I find this code here on stackoverflow but a don´t really undusted 
    ; ax = x
    mov bl, al     ; bx = x
    shl bl, 3      ; bx = 8 * x
    add al, bl     ; ax = 9 * x
    shl bl, 2      ; bx = 32 * x
    add al, bl     ; ax = 41 * x
```

Comment: `shl` seems to be the only useful one in this context. Shifting left is the same as multiplying with a power of two. Shl 1 is *2 shl 2 is *4, and so on. You'll need `add` as well to do the other ones. To do e.g. 6 you can make a copy, shift one of them 1 place left, the other two, then add them together for the result.

Comment: Without `add` and conditional branches, you won't be able to implement the normal shift-and-add algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication).  You don't need `test` or `cmp`, ideally you can `jc` on the bit shifted out, or at worst use `rol`+`ror` by 1 to set ZF like `test al,al` would.

Comment: Are you supposed to multiply two *constants*, or the multiplier is a constant you bake into your pattern of shifting and adding (according to the set bits in the binary place-value)?  Like `x*5` is `x * 4 + x*1` decomposing into powers of two?  That's straightforward with shifts and adds.  Further optimizations can be stuff like `x*7` as `x*8 - x*1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performing multiplication without using the `mul` instruction is clear enough, but saying you can only use `shl`, `shr`, `rol`, and `ror` instructions is not sufficient to solve this task.
As an example see the below subroutine that manages to multiply without the use of the `mul` instruction:

```
; IN (al=first number [0,9], ah=second number [0,9]) OUT (ax=product [0,81])
SmallMul:
  mov [$+6], al ; This overwrites the default operand of AAD
  mov al, 0
  aad          ; -> AX is product
  ret
```

> and using `add` and `sub` it is possible to make this program ?

Yes, using **repeated addition** and as long as you don't expect to *only* use `add` and `sub` because you'll always need at least some branching instruction to create a loop. And even if you would avoid creating a loop by means of unrolling, you would still have to test and branch on some exit condition.

```
example: 5 * 3  -->  0 + 5 + 5 + 5
                      <--- 3x --->
```

```
; IN (al=first number [0,9], bl=second number [0,9]) OUT (cl=product [0,81])
SmallMul:
    sub  cl, cl  ; Sets CL=0
.a: add  cl, al
    sub  bl, 1
    jnz  .a      ; Jumps BL-1 times (possibly 255 times!)
    ret
```

- If ever the second number in BL were zero, <strike>then this simple code will fail!</strike> then this simple code will be very inefficiently iterating 256 times! Nonetheless, it will produce the correct result (which is 0)
- As an optimization we can choose the smallest of the two numbers to control the loop. Less iterations is a good thing.

```
; IN (al=first number [0,9], bl=second number [0,9]) OUT (cl=product [0,81])
SmallMul:
    sub  cl, cl  ; Sets CL=0
    cmp  bl, al
    jbe  .b
    xchg bl, al
    jmp  .b
.a: add  cl, al
.b: sub  bl, 1
    jns  .a      ; Jumps BL times
    ret
```

---

A simple version of the **shift and add** algorithm:

```
; IN (al=first number [0,9], bl=second number [0,9]) OUT (cl=product [0,81])
SmallMul:
    sub  cl, cl  ; Sets CL=0
    jmp  .c
.a: add  cl, al
.b: shl  al, 1   ; Doubles AL, same as `ADD AL, AL`
.c: shr  bl, 1   ; Halves BL
    jc   .a      ; Shifted out a 1 bit, so go ADD
    jnz  .b      ; Jumps for as long as BL has non-zero bits
    ret
```

- There's no problem with the second number in BL being zero.
- As an optimization we can choose the smallest of the two numbers to control the loop. Less iterations is a good thing.

```
; IN (al=first number [0,9], bl=second number [0,9]) OUT (cl=product [0,81])
SmallMul:
    sub  cl, cl  ; Sets CL=0
    cmp  bl, al
    jbe  .c
    xchg bl, al
    jmp  .c
.a: add  cl, al
.b: shl  al, 1   ; Doubles AL, same as `ADD AL, AL`
.c: shr  bl, 1   ; Halves BL
    jc   .a      ; Shifted out a 1 bit, so go ADD
    jnz  .b      ; Jumps for as long as BL has non-zero bits
    ret
```

Comment: and using add and sub it is possible to make this program ?

Comment: `xor same, same` is the typical zeroing idiom. I would use either that or just `mov`

Comment: @ecm I purposely used `sub cl, cl` because they were asking for a solution with `add` and `sub`.  In line with how the original question was phrased, I tried to reduce the number of additional instructions in my examples.

Comment: @SepRoland Fair enough.

Comment: Multiply by a runtime variable requires a conditional branch if you're going to loop.  Or CMOV or an emulation of it (perhaps with `shl`/`sar`) if you're going to fully unroll shift-and-add for all 16 bit-positions.  You answered "yes" to the question of whether `add` and `sub` could do the job, but your code also used `jnz`.  Branching is a fundamental operation you can't emulate (except maybe with fault-handling hacks), it's important to mention it's required.  Unless one of the operands is a fixed constant, then you can just bake its set bits into your sequence of shift/add.

Comment: @GolfBravoSierra I don't see why not. If you write out the multiplication on paper and factor the coefficients into powers of 2 as much as possible, you should get a simpler form. Typically, `mul` can be rewritten as a combination of bit-shifts and adds and it will be faster once rewritten that way. I imagine there's a certain threshold where if you have too many instructions it stops being faster, but I don't know what that limit is.